# TensorFlow build fails with `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: gcc, tensorflow

Building TensorFlow with gcc version 4.8.5 or 5.4.0 gives an error:

> bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6:
>   version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by
>   bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)

Tried to add linker flags in CROSSTOOL.tpl file in Tensorflow, however it didn't help.

Comment: Which system is that? If ubuntu, did you tried: `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`?

Answer (score 1):

You built your app with version of GCC that's newer than your host GCC. So your app uses symbols which are not present in host libstdc++ which causes runtime linker to fail.

You can solve this by linking your app with `-Wl,-rpath,path/to/new/libs` or setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately.